# Android map examples

Tags: android, android-mapview

Where can i find mapviews example?

-adding point to map
-clicking that points, and then show up a layer on that point
-create a way from point1 to point2

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's official site has a hello-mapview tutorial, see the following link;

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html